# Initializing 2d array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want a 2d array to be initialized as follows

```
1 0 0 0
0 2 0 0
0 0 3 0
0 0 0 4
```

When input string `"1234"` is given.

My function to do this is as follows

```
def fun(str)
    maxlength = Array.new(str.length,Array.new(str.length,0))
    (0..str.length-1).each do |i|
        maxlength[i][i] = str[i].to_i
    end
    print maxlength
end

print fun("1234")
```

this gives me

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Which is not what I want.

**How to get the output I want ?**

Comment: Put a new array in *each* of the first array's references, not the same one as you're doing now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest problem here is that you're not creating a two dimensional array like you think you are, but instead you're creating *two arrays*. This is because you're passing in a singular array as a default, not a block that can generate them.

What you were expecting was this:

```
array1 = [ array21, array22, array23, array24 ]
```

What you were actually getting is this:

```
array1 = [ array2, array2, array2, array2 ]
```

This is easily fixed by converting the last argument to a block:

```
def fun(str)
    maxlength = Array.new(str.length) { Array.new(str.length,0) }
    str.chars.collect(&:to_i).each_with_index do |v,i|
        maxlength[i][i] = v
    end
    print maxlength
end

print fun("1234")
```

I've also switched to using `chars` which splits up the string as you want.

So the problem was that you were setting the positions correctly, but as all the second level arrays were the same array, you didn't get the result you were expecting.

**Update:** Added `each_with_index` from Chris's answer which makes this work with arbitrary numbers.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you use the class method [Matrix::diagonal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-diagonal):

```
require 'Matrix'

str = "1234"

Matrix.diagonal(*(str.chars.map(&:to_i))).to_a
  # => [[1, 0, 0, 0],
  #     [0, 2, 0, 0],
  #     [0, 0, 3, 0],
  #     [0, 0, 0, 4]]
```

Another way:

```
Array.new(str.size) {|i| Array.new(str.size) {|j| (i==j) ? str[i].to_i : 0}}
  # => [[1, 0, 0, 0],
  #     [0, 2, 0, 0],
  #     [0, 0, 3, 0],
  #     [0, 0, 0, 4]]
```

Comment: beautiful. as a newbie to ruby, the second solution demonstrated the expressiveness. it's sort-of like list -comprehension in python. only more C like.

Answer (score 2):

Another one-liner for you:

```
"1234".chars.map.with_index {|v, i| Array.new(4, 0).tap {|a| a[i] = v.to_i } }
```

This just creates N arrays, one for each character in the string, and sets the `i`th index of each array to the value of that character in the string.

Edit: Another fun solution:

```
"1234".chars.map.with_index {|c, i| [c.to_i].fill(0, 1..4).rotate(-i) }
```

This creates four arrays consisting of `[value, 0, 0, 0]` and then uses `Array#rotate` to shift the value into the right position.

And another solution, which exploits the fact that there are four 0 values between each pair of non-zero values:

```
"1234".chars.flat_map {|c| [c.to_i].fill(0, 1..4) }.each_slice(4).take(4)
```

Comment: Was just going to say `chars` is where it's at for this but you beat me to it on an edit. The `with_index` part is actually missing in the original, so it only worked by coincidence. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: what's happening here ? i know what map is, but that's about it. i don't see the lambda that it's taking or the list it's working on.

Comment: @anu `map` creates an enumerator over the receiver. `with_index` amends the enumerator to pass both the value and index to the block. `Array.new(4, 0)` creates a new array of 4 elements, where each element is `0`. `tap` passes the tapped object to the block, then returns the tapped object, letting us operate on it before returning it to the map block. In this case, we tap the newly-created array to set its `i`th element to the integer value of the character passed to `map`.